# How to access 'this' class instance view or layout's width and height from XAML? (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms.

I want to access this's width from XAML.

In this example, How to set fontsize of Label depends on width of AbsoluteLayout?
I know using ValueConverter, but don't know how to access AbsoluteLayout's width.

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        x:Class="xxx">
    <Label AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Text="SOME TEXT" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the properties through pure XAML, but you first need to give the element a `x:Name`. You can then use a View-to-View binding to access the read-only Width value. It would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        xmlns:conv="NameSpace.With.My.Converter"
        x:Class="xxx"
        x:Name="Container">
    <AbsoluteLayout.Resources>
        <conv:MyConverterClass x:Key="MyConverter">
    </AbsoluteLayout.Resources>
    <Label AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 1, 1"
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
           Text="SOME TEXT"
           FontSize="{Binding Source={x:Reference Container}, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

This example expects you to define a value converter (named `NameSpace.With.My.Converter.MyConverterClass` above) that can take a double-precision value and compute an appropriate FontSize value from it.

Comment: Thanks Keith. It helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SizeChanged`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeChanged/) event to listen for size changes. Every `View` has a `Width` and `Height` property which is set after that event is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I override OnSizeAllocated.

Comment: Is there no way to do it using only XAML?

Comment: No, how would you even write code in XAML in the first place?